# PHP safe for path traversal?

Tags: php, code-injection

Is this php script safe for path traversal, null byte injection etc? I have tested by myself but I 
don`t know sure...

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['p'])) {
    $allowedPages = array();
    $openDir = opendir('./pages/');

    while(false !== ($entry = readdir($openDir))) {
        $allowedPages[] = $entry;
    }

    closedir($openDir);

    $_GET['p'] = preg_replace('/([^.]+)(?:\.[^.]+)?$/', "$1.php", $_GET['p']);
    $_GET['p'] = preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '.php', $_GET['p']);

    if(in_array($_GET['p'], $allowedPages)) {
        include './pages/'.$_GET['p'];
    } else {
        header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
        header("Location: ./404");
        exit();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Most safe in this regard is a script that only allows parameters from a whitelist …

Comment: @CBroe Guess what `$allowedPages` is used for.